# Testing function which checks if cookies are enabled with Qunit

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, qunit

I have the following function which checks if cookies are enabled in a user's browser:

```
CookiesEnabled: function() {
    var cookieEnabled = navigator.cookieEnabled;
    if (!cookieEnabled) {
        document.cookie = "test_cookie";
        cookieEnabled = document.cookie.indexOf("test_cookie") != -1;
    }

    return cookieEnabled;
},
```

I want to unit test that this works using Sinon/Qunit but am unsure of how to approach this properly as I am not very experienced using Sinon or QUnit. Here is my attempt at putting together a test:

```
QUnit.test("CookiesEnabled - returns true if user has enabled cookies in their browser", function (assert) {
    sinon.stub(CookieHelper, "CookiesEnabled")
         .callsFake(function () {});

    var result = CookieHelper.CookiesEnabled();

    Assert.Equal(result, true);

    CookieHelper.CookiesEnabled.restore();
});
```

Please can anyone point me in the right direction for unit testing this method using Qunit and Sinon? Thank you.

**UPDATED ATTEMPT:**

```
QUnit.test("CookiesEnabled - returns true if user has enabled cookies in their browser", function (assert) {
    sinon.stub(navigator, "cookieEnabled").callsFake(function () {
        return true;
    });

    var result = CookieHelper.CookiesEnabled();

    assert.equal(result, true);

});
```

Comment: If you are wanting to test the CookiesEnabled method, stubbing it out with a fake method doesn't really make sense.

Comment: The part that you should be mocking/stubbing should be the value of `navigator.cookieEnabled`

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Taplar, I have edited my answer with my updated attempt - is this a better approach ?

Comment: Is `cookieEnabled` actually a function?

Comment: @Taplar no it is a property

Comment: So see if you can directly change what the value is, or see if it is a readonly property.  If it is not a readonly property, you should just be able to change it.  If you cannot do that, then you will probably have to spy/mock the `navigator` object and fake out the cookieEnabled value.  I am unfamiliar with sinon and how you would do that, but that is the functionality you are after.

Comment: Thanks @Taplar, so I can literally do something like: 

  `navigator.cookieEnabled = true; `

?

Comment: If that property is not a readonly property, sure

Comment: @Taplar unfortunately it is readonly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, `window.navigator` is readonly. There are some things you could try to fake out the browser, but really, you should just inject the properties you're interested in for the function to use. This way you can override the browser setting or test it! Notice the addition of two arguments (since you also need to bypass your double-checking of cookie setting).

The additional `flag` argument is a boolean that essentially tells the function what the value of `cookieEnabled` should be (versus using `navigator.cookieEnabled`). However, if that parameter is missing, the code will use the browser setting. In other words, it's a way to "inject" the value you want, very useful in testing. This isn't ideal, but not much else you can without a lot more work and mocking (using a headless browser with cookies disabled).

Here's a jsfiddle of this working: https://jsfiddle.net/e5mtpboy/

```
CookiesEnabled: function(flag, bypassTest) {
    var cookieEnabled = typeof(flag) === 'boolean' ? flag : navigator.cookieEnabled;
    if (!cookieEnabled && !bypassTest) {
        document.cookie = "test_cookie";
        cookieEnabled = document.cookie.indexOf("test_cookie") != -1;
    }

    return cookieEnabled;
}
```

Then in your tests:

```
QUnit.test("CookiesEnabled - returns true if user has enabled cookies in their browser", function (assert) {
    var result = CookieHelper.CookiesEnabled(true);
    assert.equal(result, true);
});

QUnit.test("CookiesEnabled - returns true if user has disabled cookies, but we can still set one", function (assert) {
    var result = CookieHelper.CookiesEnabled(false);
    assert.equal(result, true);
});

QUnit.test("CookiesEnabled - returns false if browser does not support cookies", function (assert) {
    var result = CookieHelper.CookiesEnabled(false, true);
    assert.equal(result, false);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @JordanKasper - please could you explain to me why I need the `flag`?

Comment: Sure, let me update the answer so it's not lost in a comment, but feel free to ask more questions

Comment: thank you, very helpful and much appreciated! If you don't mind updating your answer to explain the bypass argument in more detail that would be great